# adding an image to listview, the listview is present in the tabwidget

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 4 tabs A,B,C and D. Each tab has a listview in it which I'm populating using the following code:

```
 TabSpec s1=tabhost1.newTabSpec("Tab A");
 s1.setIndicator("A",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.A));
 s1.setContent(R.id.listV1);
 tabhost1.addTab(s1);

 listview1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1);
 listview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab1content)));
```

Now I want to add an image for each of the item in the listview, any leads on how do I go about in doing it?

Comment: show the getView method of your custom adapter which you are using to set the image for a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getCount() {  //returns the size of your list
        if (imgDetails != null) {
            return imgDetails.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details_cell_view, null); // create an xml to inflate and put an imageview , textview in it.
        }
        String str = imgDetails.get(arg0).getId();
        if(str.equals("1"))
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_details_img)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_1);
        if(str.equals("2"))
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_details_img)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_2);
        if(str.equals("3"))
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_details_img)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_3);
        if(str.equals("4"))
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_details_img)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_4);


        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_details_txt)).setText(imgDetails.get(arg0).getText());
       //to set an arrow at the right of each row
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.right_arrow)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_img);
        convertView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 0);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom ListAdapter where you will set the images to list items. Set this adapter as the ListAdapter for this list using

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1);
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this));
```

Check this tutorial on how to create Custom Adapters
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: I have tried that before. The problem I'm facing with that is I'm getting the same image for all the rows in the listview. How do I change the image for each row?

Comment: That would be based on how you are binding your view inside ListAdapter. If you bind your views properly, this shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps you can share code for your ListAdapter

Comment: listview2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV2);           
           listview2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab2content)));


Another problem I'm facing is that I have 4 different ListViews (one for each tab), so I cannot use the same android:id="@android:id/list" with the same id four times in my project because I think it would conflict in the R.java file.

Comment: sorry for the clumsy writing, I'm not able to format comments here!

Comment: comments cannot be formatted, you need to edit your question and paste code there if you want. As I said you need to use Custom Adapter, what you are using here is a default Array Adapter. Please check the link I gave in my answer to learn creating Custom Adapters